# Iterating over dictionary keys in python after a certain key in python

Tags: python, dictionary

The requirement is to iterate over every pair of unique key combination in python and get intersection list of values for every pair of key. To achieve this I am iterating over keys twice and in second iteration I am bypassing all the keys having lesser value of key compare to key of first iteration -

```
for key1, val1 in dict.iteritems():
    for key2, val2 in dict.iteritems():
       if key2 <= key1:
          continue
       else:
          #vertices common to both key1 and key2 will be
          #in intersection list of its values
          neighbours  = [val for val in val1 if val in val2]
          #--Further processing on list of neighbours
```

As mentioned in others post I can create combination of dictionary keys and iterate over it but as I have to process values simultaneously I used above approach.

What will be most pythonic and efficient way to achieve this ?

Comment: Well, the order is arbitrary, but it shouldn't change between iterations, at the very least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are much better tools for this; use the [`itertools.combinations()` generator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to pair every key with every other key:

```
from itertools import combinations

for (key1, val1), (key2, val2) in combinations(dictionary.items(), 2):
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> dictionary = {'foo': 'bar', 'spam': 'eggs', 'monty': 'python'}
>>> for (key1, val1), (key2, val2) in combinations(dictionary.items(), 2):
...     print('Combining {!r}: {!r} with {!r}: {!r}'.format(key1, val1, key2, val2))
...
Combining 'foo': 'bar' with 'monty': 'python'
Combining 'foo': 'bar' with 'spam': 'eggs'
Combining 'monty': 'python' with 'spam': 'eggs'
```

You may want to use *sets* to calculate the intersections:

```
neighbours = set(val1).intersection(val2)
```